# C++ compile time polymorphism doubt?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Below program contains two show() functions in parent and child classes, but first show() function takes FLOAT argument and second show() function takes INT argument.

.If I call show(10.1234) function by passing float argument, it should call class A's show(float a) function , but it calls class B's show(int b).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
        float a;
public:
        void show(float a)
        {
                this->a = a;
                cout<<"\n A's show() function called : "<<this->a<<endl;
        }
};

class B : public A{
        int b;
public:
        void show(int b)
        {
                this->b = b;
                cout<<"\n B's show() function called : "<<this->b<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
        float i=10.1234;
        B Bobject;
        Bobject.show((float) i);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
B's show() function called : 10
```

Expected output:

```
A's show() function called : 10.1234
```

Why g++ compiler chosen wrong `show()` function i.e `class B`'s `show(int b)` function ?

Comment: You should rephrase the question for something in the lines of: compile time overload resolution or the like... Compile time polymorphism is usually interpreted as using templates to achieve something similar to polymorphism at compile time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a function in a derived class that has the same name as a function in the base class, it hides all of the functions in the base class.  You either need to rename your function, or use a using declaration in your derived class:

```
using A::show;
```

or, you can explicitly call the base class function:

```
Bobject.A::show(i);
```

Comment: +1 - i didn't know about the using directive to unhide hidden functions. yay.

Comment: @Chris: using directive is what imports a namespace. Different thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no polymorphism involved here. You should declare your functions `virtual` to make them polymorphic, and make them have the same signature.

Comment: Some people call function overloading "compile-time polymorphism", although in C++ it usually refers to CRTP.

Comment: I am using show() function with different sugnaturtes, so Virtual key word not required. If signaturessame, then only we suppose to use  Virtual key word. Correect me if I am wrong ?

Comment: @Nemanja Interesting, never heard of that. Although I see the analogy, IMHO it is imprecise use of the term. Just my 2 cents :-)

Comment: @siva That's my point. In other words, the title of your post is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `using` declaration.

```
class B : public A{
        int b;
public:
        using A::show;
        …
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing things:
If you had 2 functions in `class A` with the following signatures:
`void Show(int a);`
`void Show(float a);`

Then the compiles would have chosen the "correct" function.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a name in a derived class, it hides the name from the base class.

You can achieve what you want by adding this to B's definition:

```
using A::show;
```

That will let you use both A's show() and B's show().